# Transfer data over sound in Android

Tags: android, audio

I want to transfer data over sound(eg : text). But I can't find anyway to resolve this problem. Program will no need connect Internet.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you able to explain what you mean by `data over sound(eg : text)`

Comment: Sounds like an acoustic modem. Google tried this an documented their results here: https://code.google.com/p/mobile-acoustic-modems-in-action/wiki/ProjectReport You can download their code here: https://code.google.com/p/mobile-acoustic-modems-in-action/downloads/list

Comment: @Sreekanth Eg: I want to send message "Hello, World!" over sound to other devices. This transfer via Sound, No need server, wifi, bluetooth, or NFC...

Comment: really interested topic, but how you are planing to connect devices with out any services..

Comment: @ChelseaDrogba  if you use third party libraries or sdk, you will need other devices to implement the library or sdk, as it will be like a "encode" and "decode"(following the common algorithm) process to send and listen resp.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit/Update**: 
Found this new option, it has bluetooth low energy functionality also, though still seems an exciting development in the data via sound prospect:

**[Sonic Notify](https://sonicnotify.com/)**:

> Sonic Notify beacons combine three technologies: Sonic Notify Audio,
>   iBeacon, and Android BLE technology to reach 95% of smartphones. The
>   range and options of the beacons' coverage are configurable via our
>   back end beacon management system.

Searching for more docs, if available, on the same.
***Update: [Available documentation](https://project.sonicnotify.com/wiki/display/DOC/Sonic+Notify+Documenation+Home)***

---

I have done it using this library and SDK:  [NearSDK](http://nearbytes.com/en/products.php#opt1) from [NearBytes](http://nearbytes.com/en/), found it quite reliable.

> NearSDK is a communication solution that uses the NearBytes Mobile SDK

The dependency being you will need this to send the data and at the other end, to listen.
**For eg.**

***To send:***

```
nearBytes = new NearBytes(YourActivity.this);
nearBytes.send(NearBytes.stringToBytes("string"));
```

***To listen:***

```
nearBytes = new NearBytes(this);
nearBytes.startListening();
nearBytes.setNearBytesListener(new NearBytes.NearBytesListener() {
                    public void OnReceiveError(int code, String msg) {
                    }

                    public void OnReceiveData(byte[] bytes) {
                     String msg = NearBytes.bytesToString(bytes);

                    }
                });
```

You can find the details at:
[Integrating the NearBytes SDK in an Android application](http://nearbytes.com/developer/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8)
and
[NB Dev area](http://nearbytes.com/developer/)

Comment: This library must internet connection :(

Comment: No, its not required. All that`s necessary are the microphone and speakers.

Comment: Your link Step 5 : 5. Open the AndroidManifest.xml file and add permissions using this code:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: The transfer of sound part works without internet, that i can confirm, i have used it like that. May be it is required for purpose of logging it on their side, else internet is not mentioned in the [Minimum Requirements](http://nearbytes.com/developer/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=78) . Atleast, write an app, run it and check..StackOverflow or Documentation won't give you a working program for your requirement :)

Comment: thanks you, now I am going to try this :)

Comment: @ChelseaDrogba did it work? options may follow now that this tech is an entering the market widely, check edit

Comment: It worked, nearbytes is good library. But We must paid a alot of money to use this

Comment: its a new technology without any back-breaking competition :)

Comment: Yes, I will try Sonic library. Seem this library is 30$ for license. 
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Take a look at Google Developers, the Internet permission is due to Android system - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioStream.html

Comment: Sonic Notify is now called Signal360, it seems.

Comment: Is it paid? Near bytes.

Comment: Nowadays we the reliable library `ggwave`. For Android: https://github.com/ggerganov/ggwave-java